# Session data is lost between two different calls on the same controller, why?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have a *"mixed"* project running Symfony 3.2.6 (SF) and Zend Framework 1 (ZF). Sometimes I need to jump from SF to ZF because not all the code has been refactored|rewritten in SF. Currently I am having issues because ZF and SF stores things in session in different ways. So far my solution was look for a SF `Request` object or for a boolean value. Take a quick look to the code below which belongs to a ZF controller:

```
abstract class MainInitController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    ...
}

class ExportfileController extends MainInitController
{
    public static function registerZendDbSelect($reportId, $select, $options = [])
    {
        $sess    = new Zend_Session_Namespace('exportfile');
        $reports = $sess->reports;
        ...
        if (isset($options['request']) && $options['request'] instanceof Request) {
            $session = new Session();
            $session->set('reports', $reports);

            return $shaKey;
        }

        $sess->reports = $reports;

        return $shaKey;
    }

    public static function fetchQuery($shaKey, $sf = false)
    {
        if ($sf) {
            $session = new Session();
            $reportS = $session->get('reports');
        } else {
            $sess    = new Zend_Session_Namespace('exportfile');
            $reportS = $sess->reports;
        }
        ...

        return $report;
    }

    public function gridexportAction()
    {
        $shaKey      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('key');
        $sf          = (bool) $this->getRequest()->getParam('sf');
        ...
        $report      = self::fetchQuery($shaKey, $sf);
        ...
    }
}
```

The method `registerZendDbSelect()` is executed when page loads. This method belongs to a ZF class but it's called from a Symfony controller:

```
class AgreementEditorGrid extends DynamicGrid
{
    ...

    protected function getExportLink()
    {
        $reportId    = 'agreement_list';
        $exportQuery = clone $this->mappedSelect;
        $exportQuery->limit();
        $blocked      = ['actions'];
        $extra_fields = [];
        $options      = [
            'report_name'                => 'Agreement',
            'blocked_fields'             => $blocked,
            'extra_fields_selects_value' => $extra_fields,
            'request'                    => $this->request,
        ];

        $exportKey = ExportfileController::registerZendDbSelect($reportId, $exportQuery, $options);

        return "/exportfile/gridexport/key/{$exportKey}/sf/1";
    }
}
```

I have checked the data stored in the session by adding this two `dump()` sentences and it looks like the following :

```
(new \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper())->dump($session->get('reports'));
(new \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper())->dump($session->getId());

array:1 [
  "48362e9fcfbe08d81ddcf534cd3fe19dfc9c8d7f" => array:4 [
    "query" => Query {#522
      -origQuery: "SELECT `agreement`.`agreement_id` AS `agreement.agreement_id`, `agreement`.`AgreementNumber` AS `agreement.AgreementNumber`, `agreement`.`StartDate` AS `agreement.StartDate`, `agreement`.`EndDate` AS `agreement.EndDate`, `agreement`.`AgreementTypeID` AS `agreement.AgreementTypeID`, `agreement`.`CFProgramLevelID` AS `agreement.CFProgramLevelID`, `agreement`.`TAMFlag` AS `agreement.TAMFlag`, `agreement`.`ParentAgreementNumber` AS `agreement.ParentAgreementNumber`, `agreement`.`DistributorID` AS `agreement.DistributorID`, `agreement`.`CustomerSiteID` AS `agreement.CustomerSiteID`, `agreement`.`Source` AS `agreement.Source`, `agreement`.`Status` AS `agreement.Status` FROM `agreement`"
      -select: null
      -query: false
      -mapFunction: null
      -paginationCount: null
      -paginationOffset: null
      -pagination: false
      -curRow: null
      -curKey: 0
    }

    ...
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/reypm/7a3bfde88ae76d518b04ef42eef776ea) is a full reference file.

The method `gridexportAction()` is called when I click on a link that's on the same page where `registerZendDbSelect()` was called.

So method `fetchQuery()` is called. I have check the content of `reports` by dumping it's content - inside `fetchQuery()` method - but surprise is empty even if the `session_id` hasn't changed:

```
$session = new Session();
$reportS = $session->get('reports');

(new \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper())->dump($session->get('reports'));
(new \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper())->dump($session->getId()); 

null
"49tig5ghqevsd7t0qqu3hkm7l0"
```

What is wrong here? I am missing some basis from Session management in Symfony or in PHP or the web at all?